# Dividing rows for specific columns by date+n in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, math

I want to divide rows in my dataframe via specific columns.

That is, I have a column named 'ticker' which has a attributes 'date' and 'price'.
I want to divide `date[i+2]` by `date[i]` where `i` and `i+2` just mean the DAY and the DAY +2 for the price of that ticker. The date is also in proper datetime format for operations using Pandas.

The data looks like:

```
date        |   ticker  |   price  |
2002-01-30        A           20
2002-01-31        A           21
2002-02-01        A           21.4
2002-02-02        A           21.3
.
.
```

That means I want to select the price based off the ticker and the DAY and the DAY + 2 specifically for each ticker to calculate the ratio `date[i+2]/date[i]`.

I've considered using `iloc` but I'm not sure how to select for specific tickers only to do the math on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('ticker')['price'].transform(lambda x: x / x.shift(2))

0         NaN
1         NaN
2    1.070000
3    1.014286
Name: price, dtype: float64
```